# Splitting comma delimited csv file with inline commas

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, csv, .net

I am splitting up a comma delimited CSV-file by using
this code below. It works fine, but some of the records in
the file contains a comma within the data, even though comma is reserved
as the delimiter. For example a record contains a description text where the user
has entered commas and my script enterprets that like the record ends.
How can I somehow get over that?

Here's an example of a line in my CSV-file. Please remark the empty records at the end of the lines can be witout the "" enclosing characters:

"1","34353434","Adam","Traxx","343","This man is the boss, please handle with respect","",,"","",,","","0",,"

This is how I read and split:

```
Sub ReadOnlineExample()
Dim line_read As String
Dim tempfilename As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim rows_skipped As Integer
Dim line_split(0 To 125) As String
Dim MortalityRates(0 To 125) As Double

 tempfilename = "C:\MortalityRateTable.csv"
 Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(tempfilename)

'Split the line into individual data
line_split = line_read.Split(",")

'Save the split data into an array
For i = 0 To UBound(line_split)
  MortalityRates(i) = line_split(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Can anyone help? Maybe it's just a simple solution I just can't see :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a proper CSV parser - [File Helpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) is a popular option.

There is also a parser from Microsoft - in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace, the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx).

These take care of the subtle aspects of CSV that most hand rolled solutions don't consider until hitting an issue.

Comment: You couldn't agree with you more!

Comment: Crap was just going to post that!

Comment: +1 - this is one wheel that really doesn't need to be re-invented.

Comment: Hi, that File.IO.TextFieldParser looks like it is tailored to my needs, I don't know why I didn't came across this before, searching for file reading solutions.

Comment: - But how can it help out my problem? Does it have built in functionality which takes care of commas inside data in quotation marks??

Comment: @micknt - Yes. That's what I meant by the "subtle aspects of CSV". These libraries deal with commas within quotes, escaped quotes and more.

Comment: That's sooo nice. I'm looking forward to try this parser within my project at work tomorrow :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is probably not correct.
Last part after sentence say: `"",,"","",,","","0",,"`

There is two base conditon:

1. delimiter mark invoke enclosint whole inner string to quote mark (if you have `x,y`, and delimiter is comma, in CSV you get `"x,y"`)
2. quote mark is escaped as double quote mark (if you have `They say "Hey!"` in CSV you get `"They say ""Hey!"""`)

Other strings will be save as you type it.

And you can not transfer your last part with this rules.
Try change commas to semicolon and import into Excel. Excel displays your example as follows:

[image]

In my country is standard CSV delimiter semicolon. 
I write this code for parsing CSV. You can try modify it for your purposes (delimiter is variable):

```
    public List<string> ParseCsvRow(char delimiter, string input)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        string step = "";
        bool escaped = false;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int position = -1;

        do
        {
            if (++position >= input.Length)
            {
                result.Add(stringBuilder.ToString());
                stringBuilder = null;
                break;
            }
            step = input.Substring(position, 1);
            switch (step)
            {
                case "\"":
                    if (stringBuilder.Length == 0 && !escaped)
                    {
                        escaped = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (position + 1 < input.Length)
                        step = input.Substring(++position, 1);
                    else
                        step = "";
                    if (step == "\"")
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append("\"");
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (step.Equals(delimiter.ToString()) && escaped)
                    {
                        result.Add(stringBuilder.ToString());
                        stringBuilder.Clear();
                        escaped = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    if (step.Equals(delimiter.ToString()) && !escaped)
                    {
                        result.Add(stringBuilder.ToString());
                        stringBuilder.Clear();
                        continue;
                    }
                    stringBuilder.Append(step);
                    continue;
            }
        } while (true);
        return result;
    }
```